# auth/web-storage-unsupported error thrown in AngularFire 2.0.1

Tags: javascript, angularfire, firebase-authentication

When I try to login into my website using firebase-authentication with a Nokia Lumia 520 Phone 'auth/web-storage-unsupported' error code is thrown. I'm using AngularFire 2.0.1. Is there any way I can work around this issue becuase some of my users still use these phones with older version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Is web storage not supported in the IE browser that ships with Nokia Lumia 520 phone?

Answer (score 1):

From [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Error)

> Thrown if the browser does not support web storage or if the user disables them.

Probably your device has disabled cookies for your website, or does not support them at all.

Answer (score 1):

Third-party cookies may be disabled in your browser. Enable them and try again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem was that firebase only work in https and localhost domain. so when I run it locally in my computer it work well. but when I test it in my phone  via an IP it suddenly throw this error. so you should find a way to run it with localhost domain. or try to just test with https enabled